# JavaFX Frozen GUI When adding Button on flow panel

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

How to add 5000 buttons or labels to flow panel without freezing GUI in JAVA FX [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr0kK.jpg)

**Why I even need so many buttons** 
well, I don't need that many but at least 500 - 1000. Coz I'm building an application [Fonticon Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GfDO.jpg)

**Slow is fine but not Freezing** 
It's ok if the application is slow and take a couple of seconds to show all button But I don't want it to freeze progress bar and GUI

**How it works** 
I have an SQLite [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrZP.jpg) with a couple of tables,
each table has a list of [values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBJfz.jpg). An object gives me ArrayList values

**What I'm looking for**
I'm looking for something like.

```
FlowPane fp = new FlowPane(); 

for(String fonticon_code : DatabaseTable.getlist()) //getlist() returns an array list of Strings
{
  fp.getChildren.add(new button().setGraphic(new FontIcon(fonticon_code)));

}
```

I also wanna be able to stop and restart Thread

**What I tired**
I tried Thread, Task, Platform.runLater(update);
but I'm not sure that I use them correctly

Comment: Hi Ash, it would help to answer if you posted the whole program. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Why do you need 5000 buttons? not even 100 are shown in your screenshot. You'd be better of using some virtualizing control, e.g. [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html). Creation & layout of 5000 nodes inevitably take pretty long and `GridView` would reduce the number of cells created to the ones visible.

Comment: @fabian I'm building an application which needs couple hundred buttons on a FlowPane. Why FlowPane u ask? everything inside FlowPane rearranges itself when resizing the window

Comment: @OliverJanKrylow Thanks you. I try my best to explain it

Comment: @kleopatra i got it.

Comment: Use `GridView` as @fabian suggested.

Comment: @Ash All of the layout managers rearrange themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [`ControlsFX`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridCell;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridView;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication287 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        ObservableList observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies());
        GridView<String> myGrid = new GridView(observableList);
        myGrid.setHorizontalCellSpacing(0);
        myGrid.setVerticalCellSpacing(0);
        myGrid.setCellFactory(gridView -> {
            return new GridCell<String>()
            {
                Button button = new Button("ABC");

                {
                    button.setPrefWidth(60);
                    button.setPrefHeight(60);
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                {
                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    else {
                        button.setFont(new Font(item, 14));
                        setGraphic(button);
                    }

                }
            };
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(myGrid);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 700);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, I never knew we can do something like that as shown in this image. Thanks a lot for taking ur time indefinitely gonna try it. but my problem is regarding JavaFX UI update threads. I want to add a button to flow panel in other thread. Without freezing everything

Comment: @Ash I changed the answer up a little bit. Using `Button` instead of `Label`. I find it interesting that most of the comments are suggesting that you abandon what you are doing and use some virtualizing control. Yet, you persist on doing what you are doing. Your problem may not be what you think it is. It may simply be you are taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Thank for your help buddy